# How to get attendes email or name from Calendar

Tags: android

```
 public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
    .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), new String[] {
        "_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation"
    }, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
// fetching calendars name
String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

// fetching calendars id
nameOfEvent.clear();
startDates.clear();
endDates.clear();
Id.clear();
descriptions.clear();
int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarContract.Events._ID);

for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

  Id.add(cursor.getString(idIdx));
  nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
  startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
  //endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
  descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
  CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
  cursor.moveToNext();
}
final String query = "(" + CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME + " = ?)";// for event Id
final String[] args = new String[] { "Test ca" };
final List<Attendee> attendeeName =
    Attendee.getAttendeesForQuery(query, args, null, context.getContentResolver(), context);
return nameOfEvent;
```

}

```
  public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
  }
```

This is my code using this code i am able to get event Name ,time and location i want to get attendess and orgniser also using calendar  from event please suggest me how to get list of attendees . Test cs is my test event

Comment: https://android-dot-google-developers.appspot.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Attendees.html try this may help you

Comment: same thing i tried but can u please tell me how to get List<Attendes> coz i am not get this class

Comment: try **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102837/7073808)** answer

Comment: while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // process the cursors
}   what i will write here this i alredy tried

Comment: store your data in your `arrayList` or what you want to perform Buddy read the question too of this answer

Comment: i understood but how i will write code for to get Attnees name? description or eventname id...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157647/discussion-between-departure-and-ultimatedevil).

Comment: Hi you understood what problem i am facing

Comment: Ya let me check what can i do

Comment: yes thanx  dear  plz suggest me

Comment: you have to read [this](https://github.com/wearemakery/calendarwrapper/tree/master/src/main/java/com/getinch/calendarwrapper) may solve your problem

Comment: Still  i am not able to understand how i will get for attendess for event  in given example it show ll attendes

Comment: See the answer below may help you

Answer (score 2):

First make all `classes` from **[Calendarwrapper](https://github.com/wearemakery/calendarwrapper/blob/master/src/main/java/com/getinch/calendarwrapper/Attendee.java)**.

Then use Below code-:

**For EVENT_ID**

```
final String query = "(" + CalendarContract.Attendees.EVENT_ID + " = ?)";// for event Id
final String[] args = new String[]{"YOUR_EVENT_ID"};
final List<Attendee> attendees = Attendee.getAttendeesForQuery(query, args, null, getContentResolver());
```

**For ATTENDEE_NAME**

```
final String query = "(" + CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME + " = ?)";// for event Id
final String[] args = new String[]{"YOUR_EVENT_ID"};
final List<Attendee> attendeeName = Attendee.getAttendeesForQuery(query, args, null, getContentResolver());
```

**For ATTENDEE_EMAIL**

```
final String query = "(" + CalendarContract.Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL + " = ?)";// for event Id
final String[] args = new String[]{"YOUR_EVENT_ID"};
final List<Attendee> attendeeEmail = Attendee.getAttendeesForQuery(query, args, null, getContentResolver());
```

**Permission Required in manifest file-:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

**EDIT**

You can pass any specific title or email address of attendee at the place of **`{"YOUR_EVENT_ID"};`**

**[See this blog for more details](http://andraskindler.com/blog/2014/calendarwrapper-a-simple-and-uncomplete-library-above-the-calendarprovider/)**

Comment: @Departure try like this or let me know what output you get

Comment: YOUR_EVENT_ID  i am unable to get this id

Comment: can u please check how i will get EventId i am trying to  but not get ateendess

Comment: i have passed event titel but still i am getting 0 attnedess while Mobiletest title event i have added two attendess @UltimateDevil

Comment: can you please update your question with recent code

Comment: please check now @UltimateDevil

Comment: have you logged attendeeName in console

Comment: yes i have but i am getting zero ..  can u check from ur side to create one Event ..

Comment: Have you add Event class from github link or not

Comment: Attendess Class i have added not Event Class

Comment: I am sorry buddy you need to add all the classes [from this link](https://github.com/wearemakery/calendarwrapper/tree/master/src/main/java/com/getinch/calendarwrapper)

Comment: or you need runtime permission if you are using API more than 23

Comment: yes that i alredy give but i am Confuse how i will get List<eVENT> from event Class cant u please tell me @UltimateDevil

Comment: you dont need to create List of events you just need to create classes of Event or Calender just like Attendees

Comment: That i have created now what i have to do @UltimateDevil

Comment: Yes look at your attendees class you may have import of another Event class just remove and try again and also check your log see if any errors found

Comment: means i dint understand can u please explain

Comment: Check into your Attendees class import did you see any import of Event class

Comment: NO there is no Event import class

Comment: still am getting issue can  please check